# iPad VGA output for the iPod app?

Tags: ipad, video, ipod, vga-adapter

I'm trying to get an iPad to play a video playlist through the VGA output cable. The only way I know of to play a video playlist is through the iPod app. The problem, is that the iPod  app doesn't output the video through the VGA cable.

Is there any way to get it to output correctly? Or is there another way to play the video playlist?

Answer (score 2):

I would just look in the app store for a video playback app that supports VGA output. Lots of them do now.

You don't need to jailbreak your phone.

Here is an app called "StreamToMe" that supports playback of your videos over 3G and Wi-Fi and has VGA output.

**StreamToMe**: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/streamtome/id325327899?mt=8#

Answer (score 0):

The App developer needs to add that API to there App. So as of now if you want to output the video through VGA you will need to jail break you iPod or find an app that supports video out through the dock connector.